# Use Index trait with HashMap in Rust

Tags: hashmap, rust

In order to test the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait, I coded a histogram.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut histogram: HashMap<char, u32> = HashMap::new();
    let chars: Vec<_> = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
        .to_lowercase()
        .chars()
        .collect();

    for c in chars {
        histogram[c] += 1;
    }

    println!("{:?}", histogram);
}
```

<sup>Test code [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=use%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3AHashMap%3B%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20histogram%3A%20HashMap%3Cchar%2C%20u32%3E%20%3D%20HashMap%3A%3Anew()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20chars%3A%20Vec%3C_%3E%20%3D%20%22Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.to_lowercase()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.chars()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect()%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for%20c%20in%20chars%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20histogram%5Bc%5D%20%2B%3D%201%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20histogram)%3B%0A%7D%0A&version=stable&backtrace=0).</sup>

But I get following type error `expected &char, found char`. If I use `histogram[&c] += 1;` instead, I get `cannot borrow as mutable`.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HashMap` only implements `Index` (and not `IndexMut`):

```
fn index(&self, index: &Q) -> &V
```

so you can't mutate `histogram[&c]`, because the returned reference `&V` is immutable.

You should use the [entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) instead:

```
for c in chars {
    let counter = histogram.entry(c).or_insert(0);
    *counter += 1;
}
```

Comment: So what can I do, if I want to update my histogram with the bracket operator? Is it possible to implement `IndexMut` for `HashMap`?

Comment: [Entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry) provides a way to do it. The example solves your problem.

Comment: @mike you can't implement `IndexMut` for `HashMap`, because only traits defined in the current crate can be implemented for a type parameter ([E0210](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0210)). I think it was not implemented in the std in favor of the entry API.

Comment: It was removed "[...] in
order to future-proof the API against the eventual inclusion of an
`IndexSet` trait." https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23559 ...Why!? This succinct updating of maps like C++ is so beautiful!